# Warning: ignoring return value of 'scanf', declared with attribute warn_unused_result

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    printf("%d", t);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the above C code using ideone.com and the following warning popped up:

> prog.c: In function ‘main’:
>   prog.c:5: warning: ignoring return value
>   of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result

Can someone help me understand this warning?

Answer (score 79):

The writer's of your libc have decided that the return value of `scanf` should not be ignored in most cases, so they have given it an attribute telling the compiler to give you a warning.

If the return value is truly not needed, then you are fine. However, it is usually best to check it to make sure you actually successfully read what you think you did.

In your case, the code could be written like this to avoid the warning (and some input errors):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int t;
    if (scanf("%d", &t) == 1) {
        printf("%d", t);
    } else {
        printf("Failed to read integer.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What I found strange: it seems the compiler emits warning about unused results, but complains only about scanf. Maybe many dont know but printf also returns a value, and it seems he doesnt complain about that discarded result there.

Comment: The compiler will only emit that warning for functions that have that particular attribute. If `printf` fails, not much you can do about it. But `scanf` can fail pretty easily. All I need to do is type `'A'` instead of an integer and your program is broken.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. This problem came just today. I have been using the same compiler so many times before but suddenly this warning came.

Comment: @Evan Teran: Ah Thx, I dont know the compiler and thought it would be a "global" flag/switch/attribute. But when its a function attribute and only some have them, then I understand.

Comment: [Here's the documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bwarn_005funused_005fresult_007d-attribute-2552) on GCC's `warn_unused_result` function attribute.  If you're using GCC (which Ideone uses) and you look in your `stdio.h` header file, you'll see that `scanf` and its relatives are tagged with the `warn_unused_result` attribute, but `printf` and its relatives are not.

Answer (score 20):

The warning (rightly) indicates that it is a bad idea not to check the return value of `scanf`. The function `scanf` has been explicitly declared (via a *gcc function attribute*) to trigger this warning if you discard its return value.

If you really want to forget about this return value, while keeping the compiler (and your conscience) happy, you can cast the return value to void:

```
(void)scanf("%d",&t);
```

Comment: GCC will still warn even when you do this. See this discussion for more info http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25509

Comment: @kraffenetti: Looks like gcc folks are being a little uptight. Anyway assigning to a dummy variable does the job.

Comment: If you assign to a dummy variable then you might get another warning, about the variable being assigned but never used.

Comment: WARNING: Many compilers will optimize away this void cast, as it is unnecessary, and then an unused variable error will still be produced.

Comment: @AffluentOwl The `void` cast is the standard convention to say “this result is unused intentionally” and universally recognized—except by gcc because someone (Stallmann?) decided 20 years ago that there should be no way to ignore a `warn_unused_result`.

Comment: `(void)! ...` can be used to at least avoid the `gcc` warning (@kraffenetti @AffluentOwl), see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66425#c34 .

Comment: what on EARTH do you mean by conscience, sir? please elaborate for the back of bus.

Answer (score 10):

I tried your example with gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3.
The warning is issued if and only if optimizing, e.g., with option -O2 or -O3.
Requesting all warnings (-Wall) doesn't matter.
The classic idiom of casting to void **has no effect**, it does not suppress the warning.

I can silence the warning by writing

```
if(scanf("%d",&t)){};
```

this works, but it's a bit obscure for my taste. Empty {} avoids yet another warning -Wempty-body

Comment: this can cause an additional empty body warning from the compiler

Comment: If I see that sort of code, with a semicolon at the end of an `if`, I'll think it may be a bug. It requires an explanatory comment at minimum.

Comment: So many upvotes for such ireesponsible, cowboy advice?? shudder

Comment: Mawg is right, you should always check the return value from scanf.  I was looking for a way to silence it, more as a sport, not as advice for good coding.  I still find it odd that (a) optimizing affects whether you get the warning, and (b) -Wall doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

Do this:

```
int main() {
    int t;
    int unused __attribute__((unused));
    unused = scanf("%d",&t);
    printf("%d",t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't look very portable.

Comment: this is a dodge around a possible error; you should check to see that the return value of scanf is what you expect. (should be 1 in this case)

Answer (score 4):

After reading all answers and comments on this page I don't see these yet another options to avoid the warning:

When **compiling** with `gcc` you can add to your command line:

> gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-result proc.c -o prog.x

**Another option** is to use `-O0` as "optimization level zero" ignores the warning.

Using cast to `(void)` is simply **useless** when compiling with `gcc`

If debugging your code, you can always use **`assert()`** as in the example bellow:

```
u = scanf("%d", &t);
assert(u == 1);
```

But now, if you turn off assert via `#define NDEBUG` you will get a `-Wunused-but-set-variable`. You can then turn off this **second warning** by one of two ways:

1. Adding **`-Wno-unused-but-set-variable`** to your `gcc` command line, or
2. Declaring the variable with attribute: **`int u __attribute__((unused));`**

As pointed out in other answer, the second option unfortunately is not very portable, although it seems the best option.

At last, the defined **MACRO** bellow can help you if you are **sure** you want to ignore the return of a given function, but you are not comfortable turning off the warnings for **all** unused returns of functions:

```
#define igr(x) {__typeof__(x) __attribute__((unused)) d=(x);} 

double __attribute__ ((warn_unused_result)) fa(void) {return 2.2;}
igr(fa());
```

---

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30994180/670521)

Comment: The `assert` is an *abuse*. If an `assert` fails, the programmer wrote buggy code. If I enter `A` into your program, your code aborts, hence it has a failure.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I agree that if you use `assert` as you are misunderstanding from my answer is indeed an `abuse`. The above answer lists various options to deal with "unused return from scanf", that is the main point. The `assert` part states *if debugging*. I think it is good to "write down" all the options as an educational informative answer so people can learn all the tools and make educated choices. That is also why I think your comment is helpful, so people won't also read this wrongly and abuse the `assert()` to do a job that is not for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this is the `IGUR()` function as seen below.  Extremely ugly, but nevertheless somewhat portable.  (For old compilers which do not understand `inline` just `#define inline /*nothing*/`, as usual.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

inline void IGUR() {}  /* Ignore GCC Unused Result */
void IGUR();  /* see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245669/490291 */

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char  buf[10*BUFSIZ];
  int   got, fl, have;

  fl    = fcntl(0, F_GETFL);
  fcntl(0, F_SETFL, fl|O_NONBLOCK);
  have = 0;
  while ((got=read(0, buf, sizeof buf))>0)
    {
      IGUR(write(1, buf, got));
      have = 1;
    }
  fcntl(0, F_SETFL, fl);
  return have;
}
```

BTW this example, nonblockingly, copies from `stdin` to `stdout` until all waiting input was read, returning `true` (0) if nothing was there, else `false` (1).  (It prevents the 1s delay in something like `while read -t1 away; do :; done` in `bash`.)

Compiles without warning under `-Wall` (Debian Jessie).

Edit: `IGUR()` needs to be defined without `inline`, too, such that it becomes available for the linker.  Else with `cc -O0` it might fail.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245669/490291

Edit2: Newer `gcc` require `inline` to be before `void`.

Comment: I just found out that you can write `read -t0.01 away` in `bash`, which adds just a 100th of a second delay.  You should not go much below that, because if the process is slowed down (like running under `strace`) the timer might hit before the `read()` is executed, hence the `read` does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it depends on what you need, if you just want to disable the warning of compiler, you can just ignore the return value of the function by the force conversion  or you can just handle it, the meaning of the `scanf` function is the count of user input.

==== update ====

You can use

`(void) scanf("%d",&t);`

to ignore the return value of `scanf`

Comment: Minus one for advocating ignoring warnings. Cleverer people than you and I are responsible for them. They tell you helpful things. Paying attention to them leads to better code quality. Ignore them at your peril, and, please, don't advocate that others ignore or supress them

Comment: whatever , I know where the warning is, and I know it will do harm to mine program. And some project may treat warning as error.  I mean to rid of warning

Comment: Get rid of warnings by handling the error, not by dodging around them...

Comment: This isn't working (anymore) for gcc 5.4.x. I still get the same warning when putting a (void) cast in front of the function.

Comment: @WoodrowDouglass Warnings aren't errors. When you see a warning you examine the line and determine if it is okay the way it is.

In some cases you really do want to ignore the return from scanf, so not having a way to remove the warning for that one line is, to put it bluntly, dumb. You don't want already-examined-and-determined-safe code to emit warnings because then you are increasing the noise/signal ratio in the compiler output.

Comment: according to the man page for scanf:
`On  success, these functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned; this can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.`

For something like scanf, ignoring return values is a recipe for buggy software. It's *always* a bad idea. that's why the warning is there in the first place.

If you think that's "already-examined-and-determined-safe", examine it again.

Comment: @WoodrowDouglass Actually it depends on what you need, if you just want to disable the warning of compiler, you can just ignore the return value of the function by the force conversion  or you can just handle it, it's the basic skill.

Comment: @WoodrowDouglass @Mawg There is a reason that warnings exist and are _not_ errors. It is good practice to build your code with `-Werror` but that makes it even more important to be able to ignore some warnings, especially if your code depends to some extent on third-party code. Going around fixing warnings you don't fully understand in third-party code is what led to the "Debian random number bug" in 2008: https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/05/random_number_b.html
So while the correct way to handle a warning is _usually_ to change your code, it's cargo cult to say it's the only way!

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone help me understand this warning?

No, but here is my contribution to the horror of warning suppression. To actively throw the return value out the window, elegance dictates wrapping our statement in a *comprehensible* lambda function, like this:

```
[&]{ return scanf("%d", &t); }();
```

My apologies.

Comment: There is an elegance to this that I like; it resembles the IIFE idiom in javascript.  But like an IIFE, be careful not to omit the trailing ()!  I think it's possible to get a warning in that case, but I got no warning with -Wall.

Answer (score 1):

scanf, printf is functions that returns value, usually in those kind of functions it's the amount of characters read or written. if an error occurs, you can catch the error also with the return code.
A good programming practice will be to look at the return value, however, I never saw someone who looks at the printf return value...

If you want the warning to disappear, you can probably change the severity of the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Since functions without arguments are valid in C, you can do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static inline void ignore_ret() {}

int main() {
   int t;
   ignore_ret(scanf("%d", &t));
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use  a surrunding if () and an empty block, the terminating semikolon has to be in the next line (to prevent additional warnings)

```
#include <stdio.h>
main (int argc, char const *argv[])  {
...
if ( scanf("%d",&n) )
    ;
...
return 0;
}
```