# C99 inline function in .c file

Tags: c, c99

I defined my function in .c (without header declaration) as here:

```
inline int func(int i) {
 return i+1;
}
```

Then in the same file below I use it:

```
...
i = func(i);
```

And during the linking I got "undefined reference to 'func'". Why?

Comment: Either make it `static` or provide a non-inline definition that the linker can find.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312597

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The `inline` model in C99 is a bit different than most people think, and in particular different from the one used by C++

`inline` is only a hint such that the compiler doesn't complain about doubly defined symbols. It doesn't guarantee that a function is inlined, nor actually that a symbol is generated, if it is needed. To force the generation of a symbol you'd have to add a sort of instantiation *after* the `inline` definition:

```
int func(int i);
```

Usually you'd have the `inline` definition in a header file, that is then included in several .c files (compilation units). And you'd only have the above line in exactly one of the compilation units. You probably only see the problem that you have because you are not using optimization for your compiler run.

So, your use case of having the `inline` in the .c file doesn't make much sense, better just use `static` for that, even an additional `inline` doesn't buy you much.

Comment: my bad, an `extern` file-scope declaration without `inline` *does* force the definition to not be an inline one

Comment: I got one question, why does this situation occur when optimization is turned off ? When I turn it on with gcc -O1 option it will just compile, what option in gcc optimization provide this code to be compiled in the proper way ?

Comment: @Lazureus, when you compile with `-O0`, I suppose that you mean that, gcc usually doesn't inline any function. So then you *must* have the symbols defined somewhere, otherwise it wouldn't find any of the `inline` declare-defined functions.

Comment: Is the prototype really needed _after_?  I did some test that seems to confirm my believe that a prototype _before_ the definition will also force the symbol generation.  Just run and see: `echo "int f(void); inline int f(void){return 42;}" | cc -x c -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -pedantic-errors -Werror -O3 -std=c99 -S - -o -`.  Is that an extension to the standard (or misinterpretation in gcc)?

Answer (score 50):

C99 inline semantics are often misunderstood. The `inline` specifier serves two purposes:

First, as a compiler hint in case of `static inline` and `extern inline` declarations. Semantics remain unchanged if you remove the specifier.

Second, in case of raw `inline` (ie without `static` or `extern`) to provide an inline definition as an alternative to an external one, which has to be present in a different translation unit. Not providing the external one is undefined behaviour, which will normally manifest as linking failure.

This is particularly useful if you want to put a function into a shared library, but also make the function body available for optimization (eg inlining or specialization). Assuming a sufficiently smart compiler, this allows you to recover many of the benefits of C++ templates without having to jump through preprocessor hoops.

Note that it's a bit more messy than I described here as having another file scope non-inline external declaration will trigger the first case as described in Jens' answer, even if the definition itself is `inline` instead of `extern inline`. This is by design so you can have have a single inline definition in a header file, which you can include into the source file that provides the external one by adding a single line for the external declaration.

Comment: this answer is somewhat obsolete - I thought there was a mistake in Jens' one, but it turned out I was mistaken...

Comment: Actually, explaining when is thus semantic useful is a valuable answer (at least to me).

Comment: Confused with "inline definition as an alternative to an external one" - so when my code calls it, which "alternative" is called??

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the way GCC handle inline function. *GCC performs inline substitution as the part of optimization*.

To remove this error use `static` before inline. Using `static` keyword force the compiler to inline this function, which makes the program compile successfully.

```
static inline int func(int i) {
 return i+1;
}
...
i = func(i);
```

Comment: But how to deal with member-functions?

Comment: @Piroxiljin: C doesn't have member functions, only C++ has that.  According to the Jens' answer on this question, the meaning of `inline` differs between C and C++.

Comment: Huh. What's going on here? I always throught `static` and `inline` were orthogonal for some reason. As in, `static` implies it must be present, while `inline` (by definition) does not. (by "not present" I mean as a defined symbol, since it would have been inlined).