# inlining when function body has no return statement

Tags: c, return, inline

I read that compiler may not perform inlining when "return" statement does not exist in function body and also in the case where return type is other than void. If it's like inlining cannot happen with functions that return anything other than void, why it needed a "return" statement for making the function inline. Assume simple code as below:

Here the function declared as inline does not have a "return" statement in its body. Does inlining happen here? Is there any way through which we can know if the inline request has been accepted and executed by compiler?

```
#include<stdio.h>
inline void call()
{
    printf("*****In call*****\n");
}

main()
{
    call();
}
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using gcc compiler

Comment: break out your disassembler.

Comment: @WhozCraig : I do not have any idea about this disassembler. can we get to know if the function is inlined or not through this?

Comment: I don't know where you read that claim, but it is nonsense.

Comment: You have either read something that is very wrong, or misunderstood what it was trying to say.

Comment: I mean once you fix your code (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245521/c99-inline-function-in-c-file/16245669#16245669)), you can send your code through to the asembler-phase to at least see if that is putting your code inline. That may still not tell the whole story if link-time-optimization modifies even further. A running disassembly from a debugger [like this one](http://pastebin.com/vgJEafR7) will tell the real tale on your platform.

Comment: @molbdnilo: yes..true.. I just went back and re-read the post. Thank you.

Comment: @WhozCraig: That was very informative. thank you. I understood how we can check if inline request is accepted by complierr or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read that compiler may not perform inlining when "return" statement
>   does not exist in function body

This is not at all true. Compiler can certainly inline void functions, but whether it does inline *any* function is upto it even if you specify `inline` keyword.

Just see here: https://goo.gl/xEg6AK

This is the generated assembly:

```
.LC0:
    .string "*****In call*****"
main:
    subq    $8, %rsp
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    call    puts
    movl    $0, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    ret
```

GCC does inline your code when compiled with `-O`. It also replaced the printf call with a simple `puts`.

Comment: thank you. I understood how we can check if inline request is accepted by complierr or not

Comment: To see the generated assembly you can use `gcc -S file.c` and see `file.s`.

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously a compiler specific question, but since you are using gcc, here is what gcc produces:

```
.cfi_startproc
subq    $8, %rsp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
movl    $.LC0, %edi
call    puts
xorl    %eax, %eax
addq    $8, %rsp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
ret
.cfi_endproc
```

where `.LC0` is your hardcoded string ([complete assembly dump](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b5801b8307e9639)). As you can see there is no call to `call` here, so yes, gcc does inline this call with `-O2`.

Answer (score 1):

The GCC compiler provides a number of extensions to the standard C language that allow you to add 'attributes' to functions (as well as to types and variables which are not relevant here).  One of these is `__attribute__((always_inline))`, which overrides the compiler's inlining algorithm.

```
#include<stdio.h>
inline void __attribute__((always_inline)) call()
{
    printf("*****In call*****\n");
}

main()
{
    call();
}
```

In this case, the instruction(s) to make the call to the `printf` library routine will be inlined at the point the `call` function appears in the calling code.

Comment: The [Inline](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html) page in the GNU Compiler documents is worth a read.