# Why is there no inline function symbol at all?

Tags: c, assembly, linker, inline

I know inline keyword should be used only in header files, in order the compiler does not complain about more definition. I am talking about plain `inline`, no `extern inline` neither `static inline`, but when I make a function inline (in source file `.c`, then the compiler does not bother to provide the symbol at all:

```
#include <stdio.h>

inline void print(char *s){
    printf(s);
}

int main(){
    print("abc");
}
```

gives:

```
.text
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "abc"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushq   %rbp    #
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #,
# a.c:8:    print("abc");
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi    #,
    call    print@PLT   #
    movl    $0, %eax    #, _3
# a.c:9: }
    popq    %rbp    #
    ret 
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

(No symbol for `print` function, thus no `call print`) and thus

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccshH3yR.o: in function `main':
(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `print'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But I do not see any correlation between `enable more function definition` (which is what `inline` keyword is for) and `if it is in source, not header, does provided the symbol at all`. I just do not understand, why had `gcc` decided for this behaviour. For those who think this is duplicate, I have already read all related questions: [When should I write the keyword 'inline' for a function/method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759300/when-should-i-write-the-keyword-inline-for-a-function-method), [Inline function in header file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34139737/inline-function-in-header-file-in-c), [What is the use of the `inline` keyword in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108159/what-is-the-use-of-the-inline-keyword-in-c), and others. But no answer for why the compiler cut off the function at all (if in source).

Comment: As indicated in the answers to the duplicate question, you just need to add `void print(char *s);` after the inline copy so that it can be instantiated as a function with external linkage.