# warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]

Tags: c

I got this error when compiling my programm in C.

> warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]

On all my call to write.

```
FLAGS : -g -Wall -Werror -Wextra -g -O2 // or -Ofast (same result)
```

> GCC Version: 5.4

It happends when I'm trying to compile with -O2 or -Ofast.

Someone can explain me, why that's not working?

Thanks :)

Comment: It's a friendly compiler warning that you are not error checking `write(2)` call - it thinks you might be interested in knowing  I/O failure.

Comment: It would appear that you are ignoring the return value of `write`. [man write](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: ignoring return value of 'scanf', declared with attribute warn\_unused\_result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271939/warning-ignoring-return-value-of-scanf-declared-with-attribute-warn-unused-r)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it is "working" but the compiler thinks you're missing something since you ignore the return value so it's giving you a warning. Not an error, although you're using `-Werror` so it will consider the warning an error and fail.

There are two solutions:

1. Add code that checks the return value, and handles any errors; OR
2. Cast the call to `(void)`, thereby explicitly saying "this return value is here but I'm not using it".

Since I/O is brittle and can fail, the first is of course generally the best approach.

Comment: Yes I know that ! But, i'm trying to understand why are there warnings ;) @KlasLindbäck

Comment: So, i've to do that? `(void)write(1, " - ", 3);` for exemple?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Thanks, didn't realize that. I edited.

Comment: @pierreafranck Yes, that casts the return value to `(void)`, which should silence the diagnostic.

Comment: @pierreafranck I suggest you go for uwind's suggestion, to use option 1.

Comment: After the cast : **show_mem.c:25:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   (void)write(1, " bytes\n", 7);**

Comment: Option 1 is working :) thanks dude

Comment: In some use cases, failures don't matter/can't be meaningfully handled. Even then, you can still handle errno == EINTR by simply repeating the same system call. Even when I'd otherwise ignore a failure, I'll still: "do { rc = write(...); } while(rc == -1 && errno == EINTR);"