# How to input just character in scanf("%d%c");

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int input;
    char ch;
    scanf("%d%c", &input, &ch);
    printf("%d %c", input, ch);
}
```

I just want ch has some character and input has trash value.

So i typed [q] and [enter].

But output is [trash value ?].

I don't know why ch has '?' not 'q'.

What happens in my buffer?

Comment: You need to give the input buffer something to feed the `%d` format specifier ... a number!

Comment: You should check the return value of `scanf` to see how many inputs were actually matched.

Comment: ALWAYS check the return value of `scanf()`. (Just to understand mediocrevegetable1 comment correctly, it is not only here where you need to check it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `scanf("%d%c", &input, &ch);`

With input `"q"`, scanf will try to interpret `'q'` as the first character of an integer (for the `"%d"` conversion) and fail... `scanf()` returns immediately with value `0` and without changing the value of `ch` (the value of `input` is indeterminate).
`"q"` is still in the input buffer ready for the next input operayion.

**Always** check the return value of `scanf()`

```
int chk = scanf("%d%c", &value, &ch);
switch (chk) {
    default: /* this didn't happen */;
             /* let the compiler writers know about this */
             break;
    case EOF: /* error */;
              /* value unchanged */
              /* ch unchanged */
              break;
    case 0: /* no input found */;
            /* value indeterminate */
            /* ch unchanged */
            break;
    case 1: /* no input for ch found */;
            /* value ok; (possibly) changed */
            /* ch indeterminate */
            break;
    case 2: /* all ok */;
            /* value ok; (possibly) changed */
            /* ch ok; (possibly) changed */
            break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent example of why you should [always check the return value of `scanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7271939/10871073) (and related functions).

The format string you give to `scanf` (`"%d%c"`) expects, as input, a valid decimal number followed (immediately) by a character. If you input `q` by itself, the function will fail to read a decimal value and stop at that point – returning `0`, because none of the arguments was successfully assigned a value. In that case, neither `input` or `ch` will have predictable values, as you have not initialized either.

Also note that, if you type in *just* a number (i.e. `12`), the terminating newline (from the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key) will be assigned to `ch`.

Here's your code with an input-check added and default values assigned to your two variables:

```c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int input = 42;
    char ch = '$';
    if (scanf("%d%c", &input, &ch) != 2) {
        printf("Error: Please input a number and a character!\n");
    }
    printf("%d %c", input, ch);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Alternatively, if (as I think you suggest in your question), you want to still read the `ch` value but leave `input` as its original ('trash') value, you can re-read the input if/when the first call to `scanf` fails. On that second call, remove the `%d` format specifier:

```c
int main(void)
{
    int input = -137; // Let's use this as a 'trash' value.
    char ch = '$';
    if (scanf("%d%c", &input, &ch) != 2) {
        if (scanf("%c", &ch) != 1) printf("Error: Failed to read anything!");
    }
    printf("%d %c", input, ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {


int input;
char ch;
scanf("%c%d", &input, &ch);
printf("%c %d",ch, input);
```

}

This code gives just the trash value as output nothing else.